# Почему функция "вешает" Google Chrome? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

При попытке проверить функцию в консоли браузера, он виснет, что я делаю не так?

Это попытка решить [это заданание на CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/515de9ae9dcfc28eb6000001/train/javascript), там output тоже ничего не выводит, я в замешательстве...

```js
function solution(str){

  var result = [];
  
   if((str.length % 2) === 0) {
     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i + 2){
       result.push(str.substr(i, 2));
     }
   } else {
   
     for (var i = 0; i < (str.length); i + 2){
       result.push(str.substr(i, 2));
     }
     
     result.push(str.substr(str.length - 1, 1) + '_');
     
     };
     
     return result;
};
```

Comment: `i + 2` такая запись не меняет переменную, нужно `i += 2`

Comment: поэтому `i` всегда ноль, отсюда бесконечный цикл

Answer (score 0):

Не `i + 2`, а `i = i + 2`.

```js
function solution(str) {
  var result = [];

  if (str.length % 2 == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
      result.push(str.substr(i, 2));
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i += 2) {
      result.push(str.substr(i, 2));
    }
    result.push(str.substr(str.length - 1, 1) + '_');
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(solution("abcdefg"));
console.log(solution("abcdefgh"));
```